# DLang: Как правильно прилинковать GUI-библиотеку DWT?

Tags: gui, компоновщик, d

В процессе ознакомления с **D**, появилось желание написать что-нибудь простенькое с **GUI**. В качестве GUI-библиотеки выбрал [DWT](https://github.com/d-widget-toolkit/dwt), т.к. кроссплатформенно и является биндингом с **SWT** (много обучающего материала по последнему).

Проект был скачан с ГитХаба, собран и перенесен в папку `C:\D\`. Методом проб и ошибок была получена работающая команда для сборки демонстрационного окошка с надписью "Hello, DWT!" посередине:

```
dmd.exe "..\src\%1" -IC:\\D\\dwt\\imp ^
-JC:\\D\\dwt\\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86\\res ^
-L+C:\\D\\dwt\\lib\\ -L+org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.lib ^
-L+dwt-base.lib -L/SUBSYSTEM:windows:4 ^
-L/rc:..\res\resource.res
```

, что соответствует следующим параметрам в `dub.json`:

```
"importPaths": ["C:\\D\\dwt\\imp"],
"stringImportPaths": ["C:\\D\\dwt\\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86\\res"],
"lflags": ["+C:\\D\\dwt\\lib\\"
   , "+org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.lib"
   , "+dwt-base.lib", "/SUBSYSTEM:windows:4"
   , "/rc:res\\resource.res"]
```

Код самой программы:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.all;
void main()
{
    auto display = new Display;
    auto shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
    auto label = new Label(shell, 0);
    label.setText("Hello, DWT!");
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed)
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    display.dispose();
}
```

И программа собирается в один в один единственный **exe** без зависимостей и на ура запускается на ОС от WinXP до Windows8. Но меня терзают серьезные сомнения, что я тут наворотил лишнего, и можно было бы как-то по-проще.

Если кто-то разумеет в **dmd** или **dub** и в тонкостях их отношений с линковщиком, подскажите, как в описанной ситуации поступил бы белый человек.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще будет, если библиотеку добавят в dub-репозиторий. Пока этого не случится, нужно прописывать пути самостоятельно.

Шаги, которые нужно сделать.

- Выбираете место для библиотеки (на вашем примере, это может быть `C:\D`)
- Открываете консоль, заходите в выбранную директорию.
- Следуете инструкции с github:

  - Клонируете репозиторий `git clone --recursive git://github.com/d-widget-toolkit/dwt.git`
  - Появится папка `C:\D\dwt` с проектом и зависимостями. Заходите в эту папку `cd dwt`
  - Выполняете сборку проекта `rdmd build base swt`.

Собственно, теперь можно подключать библиотеку в свой проект. Для компиляции из командной строки нужно будет выполнить

```
dmd main.d -IC:\D\dwt\imp -JC:\D\dwt\res -L+C:\D\dwt\lib\ "-L+org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.lib" "-L+dwt-base.lib" -L/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS:4.0`
```

Именно это и написано в инструкции на гитхабе:

```
dmd main.d -I<dwt>\imp -J<dwt>\res -L+<dwt>\lib\ ^
"-L+org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.lib" "-L+dwt-base.lib" ^
-L/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS:4.0
```

`<dwt>` - это путь к директории самого `dwt`, лезть к `res` в `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86` не требуется, так как нужный `res` лежит в самой `dwt`.

Итог у вас почти правильный. Если внимательно следовать инструкции к библиотеке, то ошибок никаких нет.

Для того, чтобы в будущем не прописывать все пути/зависимости в проекте, можно сделать "пустой" проект и впоследствии просто копировать его в качестве нового.

P.S. Лично я использую библиотеку [DlangUI](https://github.com/buggins/dlangui). Кроссплатформенная, с широкими возможностями, интерфейсы можно удобно собирать, используя разметку DML (похожую на QML) и др. Есть [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/253923/) от автора.

P.P.S. Обязательно используйте фигурные скобки во `while`

```
while (!shell.isDisposed)
{
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
```

Иначе, добавив ещё какую-нибудь строку кода, можно получить некорректную логику программы.

Comment: Пробовал DlangUI. Проходя руководство "Getting Started", не смог понять, как убрать командную строку, которая появляется вместе с графическим окном. И ещё приложение из каких-то своих соображений начинает вести лог - странное поведение по умолчанию.

Comment: сейчас не могу проверить, но первая мысль - а при release компиляции то же самое?

Comment: наверно,правильнее это будет оформить отдельным вопросом

Comment: [DLang: Странности в поведении приложений под GUI-библиотекой DlangUI (Windows)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426726)

Comment: DlangUI - исправлено появление окна (см. вопрос по ссылке выше)