# DLang: Странности в поведении приложений под GUI-библиотекой DlangUI (Windows)

Tags: gui, d

Пробуя DlangUI, столкнулся необъяснимым (для моего уровня знаний) поведением приложений после сборки (Windows 7).

Следуя руководству новичка из [этой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/253923/) статьи, успешно собрал "Hello world"-приложение, которое запускается командой `dub run`. Но при запуске этого же приложения из корневого каталога проекта или из папки `.dub\build` обнаружились две несуразности непонятной мне природы:

1. GUI-приложение стартует вместе с командной строкой
2. Приложение пишет лог в файл `ui.log` (на самом деле, это происходит и при запуске через `dub`)

Точно так же себя ведет второе предложенное в статье тестовое приложение, собираемое командой:

```
dub fetch dlangui
dub run dlangui:example1
```

Такое же поведение и в release-сборке, полученной командой:

```
dub build --build=release
```

Беглое гугление по теме результатов не дало, из чего делаю вывод, что решение элементарное, но идеи у меня уже закончились.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Обновление DlangUI v0.6.31**

- во все примеры добавил win_app.def
- в win32/release создается stderr логгер вместо файла
- в README добавлена информация про .def файл

Если нужен лог в файл в win32/release - можно сделать это вручную в UIAppMain - добавить строчку

```
Log.setFileLogger(std.stdio.File("ui.log", "w"));
```

Answer (score 2):

добавьте при копмиляции [module definition file (.def)](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/ctgDefFiles.html) с содержимым:

```
EXETYPE NT
SUBSYSTEM WINDOWS
```

[Судя по вики](http://wiki.dlang.org/D_for_Win32#Windows_Executables), должно помочь.

Для dub .def можно подключить добавив в dub.json

```
"sourceFiles": ["$PACKAGE_DIR/source/win_app.def"]
```

Comment: Да, вы правы!
Для этого в `dub.json` нужно добавить `"sourceFiles": ["$PACKAGE_DIR/source/win_app.def"]`.
Закрою вопрос, когда [получу ответ от создателя библиотеки](https://gitter.im/buggins/dlangui) на вторую его половину 
(постфактум осознаю, что объединять эти два вопроса было плохой идеей).
Не лайкнул ваш ответ по причине нехватки 2х баллов в репутации.

Comment: @TimushevRoman можете просто отредактировать мой ответ. за заапрувленную правку как раз дают два балла )